# Igor pro string manipulation function documentation

Tags: igor

I am trying to find documentation for string manipulation in igor pro. In particular, for functions for appending and stripping elements from strings. Does igor pro have such built in functions and is there somewhere that lists all the string mananipulation functions in igor pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic string manipulation:

```
string str = "abcd"
print str[1,inf] // prints bcd

string suffix = "1234"
str += suffix
print str // prints abcd1234
```

String functions:

```
cmpstr: Compare two strings for equality
strlen: Length of a string
str2num/num2str/num2istr: Convert from/to strings
LowerStr/UpperStr: Change case
strsearch: Search inside a string
StringMatch/GrepString: Fancy string matching using wildcards/regexps
RemoveEnding: Removes a known suffix from a string
```

All string functions are listed in V-10 of the PDF manual.

Igor specialities:

- `strswitch` is a switch statement for strings
- The ternary operator (`? :`) can not be used with strings, use `SelectString`
- Lists of strings are plain strings with a single character separator
- Key value pairs are managed with `StringByKey/ReplaceStringByKey/NumberByKey`